# XSLT copy-of and character 8211

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am using xslt 2.0 and using copy-of to copy most an XML.

I have this XML (the part which is problematic):

```
<nitf>
<body>
<table class="4-col">
<tr><td>Sarpsborg &#8211; Høvik</td><td>6</td><td>-</td><td>8</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</nitf>
```

And here is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:output indent="yes" media-type="text/xml" method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-15" />

<xsl:template name="createBody">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/nitf/body"  />
</xsl:template>
```

The Output is:

```
<nitf>
<body>
    <table class="4-col">
        <tr>
           <td>Sarpsborg &#x2013; Høvik</td>
           <td>6</td>
           <td>-</td>
           <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</nitf>
```

The intended output should have been:

```
<nitf>
<body>
    <table class="4-col">
        <tr>
           <td>Sarpsborg &#8211; Høvik</td>
           <td>6</td>
           <td>-</td>
           <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</nitf>
```

**The solution**

Thanks to Martin Honnen I was able to get the correct output by adding reference to some saxon extensions. Because we have a commercial license I was able to use this extension. 
You add it by adding the saxon namespace to the stylesheet root node:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
```

Then you add the following to the xsl:output element: saxon:character-representation="decimal"
Your output shall then look like this (or at least mine is):

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-15" saxon:character-representation="decimal" />
```

Martin Honnen is linking to this extension in his answer, so please do read up on how this extension work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSLT processor parses your input XML with an XML parser into a a tree of nodes with Unicode characters. That tree does not contain any character references at all but simply the characters. If you copy a text node to the output and serialize the output to a file, the XSLT processor serializes the text node and escapes any characters as far as needed by the serialization rules and the encoding. A Unicode character that can not be represented in the chosen output encoding will be escaped as needed, but the choice of encoding (i.e. hexadecimal or decimal) is up to the XSLT processor.

If you use the commercial versions of Saxon, then see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html and try to set `<xsl:output saxon:character-representation="decimal" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>`, to enforce a decimal representation.

If you really need to preserve character references then you need to preprocess the XML, for instance wit LexEv http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/, to turn them into markup you can process.

Comment: That was just awesome. It fixed my problem with ease.